# NXLog shipping Windows Events and SeverityValue

Tags: nxlog

I have NXLog shipping windows event logs to my logstash server.  However, I'm finding that the original severity level in the windows event log, , is being replaced with "SeverityValue" and "Severity".

And what is the mapping?  If Level is 4 for Information, 3 for Warning, 2 for Error and 1 for Critical, what is the NXLog output going to me?

And why does NXLog do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find the answer in the docs, however, the source code had it.  Going here: https://github.com/lamby/pkg-nxlog-ce/blob/master/src/common/error_debug.h#L16

We see where the loglevel is being set.

`typedef enum nx_loglevel_t
    {
       NX_LOGLEVEL_DEBUG        = 1,
       NX_LOGLEVEL_INFO,
       NX_LOGLEVEL_WARNING,
       NX_LOGLEVEL_ERROR,
       NX_LOGLEVEL_CRITICAL,
    } nx_loglevel_t;`

NXLog is effectively trying to baseline all log errors so that they are comparable no matter what the source.